# Decomposition of AsH3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, oxidation-state, decomposition

In German problems olympiad 2014, the solution says that decomposition of arsine is not a redox reaction. Why would that be? Shouldn't H turn from -1 to 0 and As from 3+ to 0?

$$\ce{2AsH3 -> 2As + 3H2}$$

Comment: If they really said so, they probably implied that with electronegativity difference that small we may just as well consider both oxidation states 0 from the start, because they are arbitrary anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Often in chemistry "facts" depend on perspective. You're right that essentially H goes from -1 to 0 and As from 3+ to 0. But in general redox reaction involve two different chemical species. In this case it is better to think of the reaction as a decomposition reaction rather than a redox reaction.

Comment: Decomposition reactions are autoredox reaction (Disproportionation ).Are they not ?